# Why do some objects initilize themselves?

Tags: java

FileSearchApp.java

```
package com.example.filesearch;

public class FileSearchApp {
    String path;
    String regex;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileSearchApp app = new FileSearchApp(); // ?

        // some othe code
    }

}
```

Why there is this line `FileSearchApp app = new FileSearchApp();`? Why would an object need to recreate itself? And there is no issue calling a method like `callMethod1();`.

Comment: Too little code to say for sure, I assume you want to call a non-`static` method on `app`

Comment: The object doesn't initialize itself. The static main method, which is not part of any object (since it is static), creates an object.

Comment: I recommend getting started with Java basics, especially on class design and keywords - start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) and read through.

Comment: Are you coming from a C++ background, where `FileSearchApp app` would create the object?

Comment: @SteveSmith, C background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`main` is `static`, without creating a new instance, you can only call other static method of it.

Comment: Clarification: a static method (_function_) or field (_global_) is on the class level, without any object instance/new.

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of methods and four types of variables. As in this case the major two are,

- Instance
- Static

If you see the keyword `static` they are static if not instance.

They are in two different places. When starting the application you are inside the `main` method and it is `static`. To access instance variables or methods like `path`, `regex` and any other instance methods you need an object. That's where the statement `new FileSearchApp()` comes in.

The method local variable `app` holds your object so you can call all the instance things inside it using that object.

```
app.path;
app.regex;
app.instanceMethod();
```